# u'articles' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, namespaces

I've been struggling to deal with this error for days, I would really appreciate if anyone could assist, I tried so many different suggestions online and all in vain:

I'm using Django 1.8.2, (python 2.7.10) and followed the example to the the T and yet I still get the following error:

```
    NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/

u'articles' is not a registered namespace

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version:     1.8.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

u'articles' is not a registered namespace

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse, line 575
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.10
Python Path:    

['/Users/mac/django-playlist/djangonautic',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

**My urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin
from .import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^accounts/$',views.about),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^articles/',include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^about/$',views.about),
    url(r'^services/$',views.services), 
    url(r'^$',views.homepage),

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**and my accounts/url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

app_name = 'accounts'
app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name="login"),
]
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

# Create your views here.
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            #log user in
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else: 
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html',{'form':form})


def login_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #login User
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:   
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{'form':form})
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Login</h1>

<br>

<form class="site-form" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: remove `app_name = 'articles'` from `accounts/urls.py`

Comment: I don't think you can use `app_name` in the `urls.py` in Django 1.8. Please upgrade to a newer version if you can - Django 1.8 has been end of life for three years. Use the latest 3.1.x release or 2.2.x LTS release if you can use Python 3, or the last 1.11.x release (which is end of life as well) if you can only use Python 2.

Comment: In Django, you can [namespace the urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) by passing  `namespace` to `include`, e.g. `url(r'^articles/',include('articles.urls', namespace='articles')),`